# Owl Carousel - Making Text inside it responsive

Tags: text, owl-carousel

I have the Owl Carousel set up and it works great, but I have text over the image that doesn't resize in response to the viewport change. The images resizes, but the text remains the same.

How can I make the text (within `p` and `div` tags) to be responsive with the images?

Comment: You can set a max-width with a value of percent.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem...I found a free theme where text is responsive with this plugin but still I don't understand what is the code to fix it...hope this can help someone

here the link of the theme:
http://w3layouts.com/demos/umbrella/web/#

look at "testimonials" section

Regards

Answer (score 0):

add this bottom: 30% !important; inside the CSS at the only screen and (max-width: 767px)  section, for the owl caption label.

Comment: A little explanation and demonstration might be helpful.

Comment: Can you enclose sections of CSS code in backticks (`)? This will make the answer much more readable.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't recommend using `!important`; it is intended for situations where you need to override CSS that you cannot change for some reason. If Owl Carousel does indeed require `!important`, then one should probably not use Own Carousel in the first place ;-)